# Post to PHP, do not reload page and update div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**EDIT: This works now, code updated.  Big thanks to Martin Amps!**

So I've been playing with this for a week now and have hacked together many examples but it hasn't worked, so I won't bother posting code since it's a mess!  I'm a jack of all trades, master of none, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Here's what I need.

---

**posttest.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="processForm" id="processForm" action="process.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="textField" name="textField" />
  <input type="hidden" id="sessionID" name="sessionID" value="myusername" />
<input type="submit" value="Process!" />
</form>

<div id="mydiv"></div>

FILLER<BR><BR>FILLER<BR><BR>FILLER<BR><BR>FILLER<BR><BR>FILLER<BR><BR>FILLER<BR><BR>FILLER<BR><BR>FILLER<BR><BR>FILLER<BR><BR>FILLER<BR><BR>
FILLER<BR><BR>FILLER<BR><BR>FILLER<BR><BR>FILLER<BR><BR>FILLER<BR><BR>FILLER<BR><BR>FILLER<BR><BR>FILLER<BR><BR>FILLER<BR><BR>FILLER<BR><BR>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#processForm').submit(function() {
  var text = $('#textField').val();
  var sid  = $('#sessionID').val();

$.ajax({
  url: "process.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: { 'text' : text, 'sessionID' : sid },
  success: function(data) {
    var result = $.parseJSON(data);
    if (result.success) {           
        // Handle your result and update your form accordingly  
        // result.data.someKey  
        $('#mydiv').text('Success! With ' + result.data);

    }
    else {
        // Error handling as applicable
    }
  }
});

    return false;
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
$someText=$_POST['text'];

$return = array('success' => false, 
            'data' => $someText
           );

if (isset($_POST['text'], $_POST['sessionID'])) {
    // Do your queries

    $return['success'] = true;
    //$return['data'] = array('someKey' => 'someValue');
    $return['data'] = $someText;
}

echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

---

I've tried so many examples, and tried making my own from scratch and can't seem to get it to work!  An example of what I'm trying to accomplish would be like when you add a comment on facebook, or a new post.

I hope someone can help out because I feel like I've already wasted a week here on this simple task.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so you want live update the display div in index.php based on the text in the input box?

Comment: There is a very simple way yet I can't say it is the best way, put the php page with the post inside an iframe then have the div be updated from a variable in sql

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please search your questions before posting them, as there are many questions like this already answered here, some of which I myself answered: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+send+data+to+php&submit=search

Comment: @SpencerMay I would strongly advise against using iFrames, as they are not longer considered valid HTML, and in my opinion, always been bad practice. They were more popular with sites from the early 2000s.

Comment: @spryno724 I don't only want to send the data, that's fine.  It's the sending, then getting a return and displaying it in a div without reloading the page is the problem.  I can't put it all together and make it work.

Comment: @XToro Ahh... I see, Martin Amps answer is what you are looking for, then...

Comment: @spryno724 Yes, it works, and I have no problem doing that, but this doesn't load the returned data into a div on index.php...  I basically want to do exactly the same as adding comments on this very page at stackoverflow...

Comment: @XToro See my answer for a possible solution.

Comment: I don't know why this was closed as "not a real question" because it was, I just edited it to remove my original question (My mistake).  Now sure how to "unedit" it back to how it was before...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to store the session variable in your page, as it's stored in a cookie already. Assuming you're using JQuery, here's a quick sample:

**The markup**

```
<form id="processForm" action="process.php" method="POST">
   <input type="text" id="textField" name="textField" />
   <input type="hidden" id="sessionID" name="sessionID" value="<?=session_id()?>" />
   <input type="submit" value="Process!" />
</form>
```

**The Javascript**

```
$('#processForm').submit(function() {
  var text = $('#textField').val();
  var sid  = $('#sessionID').val();

  $.ajax({
    url: "process.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 'text' : text, 'sessionID' : sid },
    success: function(data) {
        var result = $.parseJSON(data);
        if (result.success) {           
            // Handle your result and update your form accordingly  
            // result.data.someKey  
        }
        else {
            // Error handling as applicable
        }
    }
   });

   return false;
});
```

**process.php**

```
<?php

$return = array('success' => false, 
                'data' => array()
               );

if (isset($_POST['text'], $_POST['sessionID'])) {
    // Do your queries

    $return['success'] = true;
    $return['data'] = array('someKey' => 'someValue');
}

echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

**Note**

You should use absolute url's and be aware the form/javascript is non obtrusive so you should make it function without ajax too.

Comment: This is almost everything I need... I can do the posting no problem, it's returning the data into a div that's troubling me.  WITHOUT reloading/refreshing the index.php page.  Basically, exactly what I'm doing right now in this comment.  Type a comment, hit the button, and a div gets updated with my comment (and background work gets done to add it to a database and format it etc etc).

Comment: So in your success function, assuming you have `<div id="yourDiv"></div>` in the markup, just do `$('#yourDiv').text(result.data.someKey);`

Comment: Hmm.  Ok, but for some reason, even though the submit function you posted returns false, it still loads process.php and shows me raw text of the process.php echo...

Comment: I think you have a javascript error so that event isn't being fired, can you show a live example and/or check your console?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the delay http://www.stardotnet.com/xtorotest/posttest.php

Comment: Sorry, in my markup I a name attribute, and the jQuery selector I used id - my mistake! It should all work now :)

Comment: Ok, the post and response works great now, but my div is still not updating...  I changed the process.php to just return the text posted to it along with sucess

Comment: <?php

$someText=$_POST['text'];

$return = array('success' => false, 
                'data' => $someText
               );

if (isset($_POST['text'], $_POST['sessionID']) && count($_SESSION)) {
    // Do your queries

    $return['success'] = true;
    //$return['data'] = array('someKey' => 'someValue');
    $return['data'] = $someText;
}

echo json_encode($return);
?>

Comment: @XToro It's because the Javascript checks for `$result['success'] == true` and you commented that out

Comment: No I didn't, I comment a line I changed.  See original post, updated and current.

Comment: @XToro your PHP is returning `{"success":false,"data":"test"}`, my best guess is because there's no session data so try removing `&& count($_SESSION)` from your condition as that may not be necessary for you.

Comment: Ok, that works, but success still returns false unless I also remove , $_POST['sessionID'] from the condition in process.php...

Comment: @XToro Glad you've got it sorted!

Comment: Ok got it, the one JS line should be data: { 'text' : text, 'sessionID' : sid },
instead of data: { 'text' : text, 'sid' : sid },.  Works great now!  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @XToro Damnit, sorry - again, my mistake for rushing. Thanks for accepting

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use a general AJAX request for this and then change the div on response?

This is using JQuery of course.

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/process.php",    
                    data: "yourData=AwesomeData&SomeOtherData=5",
                    success: function(data){
                        //Update the div
                    },
                    error: function(request){
                        //Something went wrong.
                    },
                });
```

Comment: Right, that will post my data to process.php, but then I need something returned FROM process.php afterwards, and then loaded into the div.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you just want to load some data from process.php via ajax. You can use the `load()` method from jquery. http://api.jquery.com/load/

In your **index.php** file:

```
$('#container').load('process.php', {'variable1' : var1, 'variable2' : var2});
```

The code above is used to submit data via ajax using the `POST` request. So you'll have to access them in the **process.php** file using `$_POST['variable1']` Then just perform your queries, I'm assuming that you already how to do that so I'm not providing an example. 
If its a multi-row result you need to store the result in an array:

```
$store = array();
foreach($result as $row){
  $store[] = array('field1'=>$row['field_name']);
}
```

Finally use `json_encode` to make the array easier to process in javascript:

```
echo json_encode($store);
```

If you need more help feel free to comment.

Comment: Yes, I want to load data from process.php, but it's data that is first sent to process.php, processed, stored in a database, reformatted, and then returned to be dynamically loaded into a div.  Like this comment box.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a web form to collect user data:

```
<form class="form">
<input class="name" type="text"/>
<input class="email" type="text"/>

<button class="submit">Send Data</button>
</form>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$('form button.submit').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        'data' : $('form').serialize(),
        'type' : 'POST',
        'url' : 'process.php',
        'success' : function(data) {
            $('div.container').html('<p>' + data + '</p>');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['name'] != "" && $_POST['email'] != "") {
    //Do some SQL processing

        echo "success";
        exit;
    }

?>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: `$.ajax` array keys shouldn't be quoted, am I right?

Comment: @AzizAG It works both ways. ;)