# jquery how to post to an array wihtout refrshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hey im trying to the data(size, color, price, qty), to an array 'add' without refreshing the page, however not sure how to do this.

example.php

```
// Add item
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        if ($_POST['id'] == $product->id) {
            break;
        }
    }

    $cart->add($product->id, $_POST['qty'], [
        'price' => $product->price,
        'color' => (isset($_POST['color'])) ? $_POST['color'] : '',
        'size' => (isset($_POST['size'])) ? $_POST['size'] : '',
    ]);

}
```

here is the code I have so far to post to 'add' without refreshing but not sure if its correct.

```
            $('.add-to-cartnon').on('click', function(){

            var $btn = $(this);
            var id = $btn.parent().parent().find('.product-id').val();
            var color = $btn.parent().parent().find('.color').val() || '';
            var qty = $btn.parent().parent().find('.quantity').val();
            var size = $btn.parent().parent().find('.size').val() || '';

                $.ajax ({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: 'example.php',
                    data: {

                        id: id,
                        color: color,
                        qty: qty,
                        size:size,
                        add:add

                    },
                    success: function(data) {


                                }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below link.

[Post to PHP, do not reload page and update div [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488219/post-to-php-do-not-reload-page-and-update-div)

Not sure if you are aware of [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON) but it will be worthwhile looking at  with this sort of problem.

You will often find on Stack Overflow a question that will be similar or the same as your current problem so searching the community will help you save time and possibly duplicating a question.

Welcome to the community!

Answer (score 0):

you can do somthing like this

```
$('.add-to-cartnon').on('click', function () {

        var $btn = $(this);
        var id = $btn.parent().parent().find('.product-id').val();
        var color = $btn.parent().parent().find('.color').val() || '';
        var qty = $btn.parent().parent().find('.quantity').val();
        var size = $btn.parent().parent().find('.size').val() || '';

        var dataArray = {id: id, color: color, qty: qty, size: size};

        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'example.php',
            data: {
                add: dataArray
            },
            success: function (data) {

            // do your code here
            }
        });
    });
```